# Slide show like thumbnails on tumblr

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I'm fairly new to customizing Tumblr sites. A client of mine has one and she wants to redo her layout. She gave me this site as a basis: http://www.marloncapuyan.net/

Basically what she wants is to have the same layout where the photos on a text post is previewed as a mini slideshow, then the details only come up when you hover one of the posts.

Is this possible in tumblr?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Tumblr, but I'm *very* familiar with jQuery/CSS. Are you asking for a Tumblr "plugin", or are you asking how to write jQuery/CSS to do this?

Comment: This website has created using a purchased template by [Prphoto.Com](http://www.prophoto.com/). If you want same layout. Please go and but the template. :D

Comment: Yes this is possible. Tumblr *themes* once rendered, are just `html`, `css` and `javascript`.